# Can you add partitions to a table in hsqldb?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hsqldb

I've been searching around and haven't seen anything about creating a new or altering an existing table to add a partition by a column for hsqldb.  Is it even possible?

When I run my environment locally, I'm able to add a partition to a table using mysql. Unfortunately, my code fails when adding a partition in my test environment which runs on hsqldb.  I also see 0 information about partitioning for hsqldb.

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( id INT, year_col INT ) PARTITION BY RANGE (year_col) ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1991), PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1995), PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1999) )

ALTER TABLE MY_TEST_TABLE ADD PARTITION (PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (5000))
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of table partitioning in the [manual](https://hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section). Do you have any reason to think hsqldb does support partitioning? It might not.

Comment: Hypersonic SQL (HyperSQL, or HSQLDB) is a database engine entirely included inside the JDBC driver. It provides great features for such a small footprint. However, it should not be considered a high end database with advanced features such as the one you want to implement.

Comment: Yes, I frequently recommend to test with the same brand and version of database you will deploy to in production. Otherwise you run the risk that your code will pass tests but fail in production. This is not something you want to be surprised by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that HSQLDB does not support partitioning as others have mentioned and there being no documentation of partitioning.